# Screen Readers & HTML

Tags: html, screen-readers

In the following link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp , There is a phrase where it says: "screen readers can "reproduce" HTML as text-to-speech, sound icons, or braille output."
what is meant by "sound icons"?

Comment: Oops, Edited ,, sorry my friend :)

Comment: google sound icons and braille output you will see it.

Comment: @Harry — It took me a couple of pages of google results to find anything useful. All the hits I was getting were quoting the wikipedia page describing screen readers. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sound icon is a description of something expressed as a sound effect instead of speech.

[This paper](http://www.icad.org/Proceedings/2007/MurphyKuber2007.pdf) gives an example:

> As the user rolls over an image or a link with the forcefeedback
>   mouse, an auditory icon is played to reinforce a
>   haptic response. In this system, the auditory icon that
>   indicates an image is a short descriptive sound clip of a
>   camera shutter clicking, suggesting a photograph or graphic.

Comment: "sound icon" what a contradictory name!

Comment: The word icon does not imply picture, even if most of the ones we encounter are pictures.

Comment: icon [ahy-kon] noun 1. a picture, image, or other representation.

Comment: "other representation"